# localhost returns different date format then online VPS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

When debugging an ASP.NET Core MVC website on Kestrel localhost the datetime output of an `IHtmlHelper` is displayed in the "swedish" 
dateformat.

I want 2017-08-03. But when running the same website on a Digitalocean Ubuntu server located in "Amsterdam" the datetime output from the same `IHtmlHelper` is displayed as 8/3/17.

I have tried the following in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("sv-SE");
        });
}
```

But that doesn't make it. What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need set `SupportedCultures` and `SupportedUICultures` too, like this:

```
var mainCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture(mainCulture, mainCulture),
    SupportedCultures = new[] { mainCulture },
    SupportedUICultures = new[] { mainCulture }
});
```

This code is for `Startup.Configure()`, for `ConfigureServices` use `services.Configure` as in your sample.